# Использование VLC плеера в tvOS, Swift

Tags: swift, framework, vlc, tvos

Мне нужно проиграть **VLC** видео на  **tvOS**. Знаю, что есть VLCKit, но никак не могу его использовать.

Как получить `TVVLCKit.framework` и в дальнейшем его использовать?

Comment: можно подробнее? вы не можете скачать? или запустить? или что?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/3pq35k/has_anyone_managed_to_build_mobilevlckitframework/

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko ну вообще, как я понимаю, чтобы его использовать, нужно получить фреймворк и импортировать его в проект. А фреймворка нет нигде и найти не могу

Comment: фреймворк под iOS будет работать и на tvOS (по крайней мере разработчики VLC так утверждают). скачать можно с cocoapods https://cocoapods.org/?q=mobilevlckit или с сайта https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko ну например, при установке через поды - выдает неподдержку tvos. А вот с сайта - я так файла-фреймворка и не нашел

Comment: по той ссылке на reddit, что я дал выше, вроде разобрались что к чему.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko к сожалению, так и не нашел решение :( Не могли бы Вы указать его?

Answer (score 1):

Для добавления в Ваше tvOS-приложения VLC можно воспользоваться [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) (думаю Вы знакомы с данным менеджером для разрешения зависимостей, если нет, то получите информацию на их официальном сайте или найдите что-то на [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)).

В Ваш Podfile добавьте строчку:

```
pod 'TVVLCKit', '3.3.9'
```

И затем установите `TVVLCKit`, введя в терминале:

```
pod install
```

Так как я показываю на примере проекта, созданного на языке Swift, то Вам придётся использовать т.н. bridging header, поэтому добавьте в Ваш проект (если раньше не добавили) такой файл и там напишите:

```
#import "TVVLCKit/TVVLCKit.h"
```

После этого перейдите в Ваш проект и выберите `UIViewController`, в котором Вы хотите показывать видео. Добавьте новый член класса:

```
let player = VLCMediaPlayer()
```

Там, где Вы собираетесь начать проигрывание видео, добавьте такой код (Swift 3.3):

```
player.drawable = self.view //Здесь Вы указываете UIView, которое будет использоваться для отрисовки
if let pathToMovie = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "видео_которое_я_хочу_смотреть", ofType: "mp4") { //видео из ресурсов приложения

    let urlToPlay = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: pathToMovie)
    player.media = VLCMedia.init(url: urlToPlay)
    player.play()
}
```